# Ground-neutral impedance

Tags: grounding-and-bonding

In the US electrical system, as I understand it, the ground and neutral wires are connected (bonded?) together at someplace.

In the past, the location of the neutral bonding was a matter of local electrical code.  (Is that still true, or is there now a single location specified in the N.E.C.?)

Ground and neutral are not generally connected at the wall socket or appliance, as a result, a small difference of voltage between ground and neutral can be observed, typically when the system is under load.  Any large voltage between these would generally indicate a fault in the wiring.

My question then is what range of impedances would be found between ground and neutral?  Also, is it possible to measure this impedance using a handheld LCR meter?  (Of course, after ensuring that any voltage present is small.)

Comment: What home improvement problem are you trying to solve? We don't really do abstract engineering discussions here.

Comment: Any voltage present can let the magic smoke out of your meter! If a measurement is made it will not be accurate.

Comment: In the US the NEC still only becomes law when adopted by local ordinance, and subject to local revisions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main panel is the required bonding point for ground and neutral per the NEC (for many years).
Measuring the impedance with the main breaker turned on can fry your LCR meter.

If you turn off your main and measure between neutral and ground the value will be based on the wiring method and distance from the main panel. Copper or aluminum and distance are used to calculate the resistance but it generally should be a low value.

Comment: Thanks.  Turning off the main breaker sounds like a very reasonable precaution.

Answer (score 1):

14 AWG wire (used on 15A circuits) is 0.002525 ohms per foot.

12 AWG wire (used on 20A circuits) is 0.001588 ohms per foot.

#14-#10 cable have the same size ground as conductors.

If you can guesstimate the cable length from outlet to panel, you can multiply that by 2 and the above number, and that will give you the expected resistance of the ground and neutral runs to the panel and back.

If the resistance is other than as expected, you can go to the panel and measure between the neutral wire land and the ground wire land, to see if the additional resistance is in the ground bar, neutral-ground equipotential bond, or neutral bar. That should be quite low since that stuff's not supposed to get hot under load.

Comment: Thank you.  I'll go ahead and measure with the main breaker turned off.  Any prediction on inductance?